# Get value from link using Regex

Tags: regex, salesforce

I have the following link `https://mytrip.com/plan#/pro/summary/1425573?as=1` and I'm trying to capture the value of `1425573` using Regex. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: assuming it'll always be 7 digits, and a value of around 7 digits ore more won't show up aside from that one, [0-9]{7}

Comment: How far have you gone into it?

Comment: I'd like to go to the `?` and then go back to the `/`, but this is in Salesforce and I don't have the look behind feature

Comment: You can't go to the `?` then back to the `/`. Regex is a left to right operation. But, that's ok. Just do `/(\d+)\?` and the item is in capture group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one using [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)...

```
(?<=\/)[0-9]+(?=\?)
```

**[Example](https://regexr.com/3pkhj)**

Comment: I don't know if SFDC supports lookahead, behind but I will try it

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract groups:
`\/([0-9]+?)\?` may work.

https://regexr.com/3pkhp